# Value missing in GDataYoutubeRating

Tags: youtube-api

I could not get the value in youtube rating.

I get the data with GData api for iphone.
I did succeeded in downloading the feeds and even the rating statistic number.

The value in GDataYouTubeRating is always nil, event after I make a success rating.

Does anyone could help?

Answer (score 0):

YouTube has switched over to like/dislike, and numeric ratings translate into one of those. 4 or 5 = like, 1 or 2 = dislike, 3 = no-op. So if you're adding a bunch of 3 numeric ratings, that won't accomplish anything.

If you're adding a rating with a value other than 3, do you see the rating reflected on the YouTube watch page for the video? Or in the user events history of the user that's authenticated?